# Did Confucius punish a correct student for arguing with an incorrect one?

Tags: history, quotes

In Indonesia there are various variants of a popular story where two students are arguing over a simple mathematics - like whether 1+1 = 2.

The incorrect student says he will kill himself if he's wrong. They appeal to the teacher, and the teacher punishes the smart student.

I can't find an English version of the story. [Here is a translated variant](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=id&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wajibbaca.com%2F2015%2F10%2Fkisah-renungan-perdebatan-murid-pintar.html)

It's a popular story. In some versions, the teacher was [Confucius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius) himself.

I found the story suspicious.

Is this correctly attributed to Confucius?

Comment: This will be tricky, because there is a bigger question of whether *any* specific text attributed to Confucius was actually due to him.

Comment: It's not in the [Analects](http://www.indiana.edu/~p374/Analects_of_Confucius_(Eno-2015).pdf) - I searched for all occurrences of "student", then for all occurrences of "kill".

Comment: Highly unlikely, as most versions of the story involve the student being whipped, and Confucianism strictly rejects corporal punishment.

Comment: Did you ever see any version of the story? I started to think that some indonesians or motivational speakers made that up. I can't find english samples.

Comment: 颜回输冠 in Chinese, generally considered not real but I don't know what sources do I need to prove a negative.

Comment: Any sample in english? Generally considered not real. So it's dubious.